# scrollbar is not appearing in android tablet web browser

Tags: android, css, tablet

I have designed a chat window in html with scrollable content. Its fine in desktop. but when i want to see that view in android tablet(asus) web browsers, the scrollbars are not appearing. But im able to move the content like scrolling. How to see the scrollbars while touchmove?

I created the application with simple html and css. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying about text area ? or full html page